# Why try to print the value in the left node and right node of the binary search tree causing a Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, data-structures, while-loop, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement the insert operation of a binary search tree using C. Why does the following code show a Segmentation fault when trying to print the value of the left and right nodes of the root?
Please explain what caused this error exactly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node *root, *temp = NULL;

void insert(int data) {
    struct node *newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    
    if (root == NULL){
        // if tree is empty insert the node as root
        root = newNode;
    }else {
        // if the tree is not empty
        temp = root;
        while(temp != NULL) {
            if(data <= root->data) {
                temp = temp->left;
            }
            if(data > root->data) {
                temp = temp->right;
            }
        }
        temp  = newNode;
    }
}
int main() {
    insert(7);
    insert(4);
    insert(8);
    printf("\n\n------%d------", root->left->data);
    printf("\n\n------%d------", root->right->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you try to explain the `insert` function to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). It contains multiple errors.

Comment: You cannot insert a new node into the tree by setting `temp` to anything. You have to find an existing node to connect the new node to, and you have to put the address of the new node in the `left` or `right` member of that new node. You will need to rewrite at least part of `insert` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `temp = newNode` only stores a pointer in the `temp` variable, not somewhere in the tree. So your tree's root node will never get any child. By consequence the main program is dereferencing a `root->left` pointer that is `NULL`, and this explains the error you get.

In order to really attach the new node at the right place in the tree, you need to modify a `left` or `right` member of some node. You can do this in several ways. One is to make `temp` a pointer-pointer, so that it will have the *address* of a `left` or `right` member. Then the assignment to `*temp`, will be an assignment to a node's `left` or `right` member, effectively extending the tree with that new node.

Here is the updated part of the code:

```
        struct node **temp = &root;
        while(*temp != NULL) {
            if(data <= root->data) {
                temp = &(*temp)->left;
            }
            if(data > root->data) {
                temp = &(*temp)->right;
            }
        }
        *temp = newNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

okay you have a few issues here,

first of all, temp will point back to newNode, as you have not copied newNode's values to **where temp is pointing now**.

second and no less important, newNode is created within the scope of insert() - therefore, root will always remain null, as root points after execution of insert() to data wich no longer exists.

I have improved your code, and this definitely works as expected

hope it has helped.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}node;

node *root=NULL; 

void insert(int data) {
    node *temp = NULL;
    if (root == NULL){
        /* if tree is empty insert the node as root*/
        root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->data=data;
    }else {
        /*if the tree is not empty*/
        temp = root;
        while(temp->left!= NULL||temp->right!=NULL) {
            if(data <= temp->data){
        if(temp->left==NULL)
            break;
        else
                    temp = temp->left;
            }
            else if(data > temp->data){
        if(temp->right==NULL)
            break;
        else
                    temp = temp->right;
            }
        }
    if(data<= temp->data){
        temp->left=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            (temp->left)->data=data;
    }
    else {
        temp->right=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            (temp->right)->data=data;
    }
    /*temp=newNode;*/
    }
}
int main() {
    insert(7);
    insert(4);
    insert(8);
    printf("\n\n------%d------", root->left->data);
    printf("\n\n------%d------", root->right->data);
    return 0;
}
```